# What is this kanji, found in a 1932 Japanese world map?

Tags: kanji, writing-identification

[image: Unknown kanji, found in 1932 map]

The map can be found at [this link](https://nla.gov.au/nla.obj-359516141/view#parent-page), with the text in question placed to the right of the Iberian Peninsula. Despite the existence of many similar kanji (notably, 逐, 遂, 隧, 燧, and 邃), I was unable to pinpoint the exact character being used.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of 旧字体?

Comment: @Leebo Although I know of it, I know essentially nothing about identification; as of right now, my only knowledge of 旧字体 comes from what tools like Jisho.org tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the old/traditional form of 遂 (the second character you listed).

You can see it under Korean Hanja in [this wiktionary page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%81%82).

Comment: That's definitely it! Thank you very kindly for your help!